# remove the anchor from col-md-9 and keep it to only image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a piece of code like this

```
<div class="col-md-9 text-center">
  <a href="#">
   <img class="img-responsive" style="position: relative;
      width: 175px; display: inline; margin-top: 3px;
      margin-left: 448px;" src="/assets/header_other/reco.png">
  </a>    
</div>
```

If you see the image has been given a `margin-left`. The trouble I am facing is, Since Its `col-md-9`, and has an anchor tag, the whole `col-md-9` is acting as an anchor tag.

How do I resolve it.

Comment: Include `a` tag inside `span`

Comment: Use CSS: '.col-md-9 a{text-decoration:none;}'

Comment: Like this `<div class="col-md-9 text-center"><span><a.....></a></span></div>`

Comment: @IamRaviteja I tried that already. It didn't work for me

Comment: you wanna remove anchor or to image in center

Comment: why are you using `margin-left: 448px;`,instead you can use `col-md-offset-*`

Comment: the trouble is not about the image but, `col-md-9` as a whole acting as a anchor is. So not sure how that'll help.

Although I tried to use `col-md-offset-*` as well with no success

Comment: @Suraj, for me, only image is acting like a tag but not col-md-9. Can you please show in fiddle? see here its normal http://jsfiddle.net/tf7z20qb/

Comment: @Leothelion If you see on the left side of the image, you can see your cursor, which I don't want

Comment: @Suraj, yes there will be hand icon as you using image tag in a tag. What is the issue then?

Comment: and in  your question you mentioned that whole col-md-9 is acting as anchor tag so edit your question please.

Comment: That's not correct, I want my anchor tag to be only on the image and nout outside

Comment: That's what mu question is @Leothelion. The cursor is showing the pointer on the whole `col-md-9` which I want to remove as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96853/discussion-between-leo-the-lion-and-suraj).

Comment: not sure. where you are getting the hand symbol other than image area? check this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/tf7z20qb/2/

Comment: well, I am confused too. But with Reoxey solution, I am able to achieve what I want to

Comment: I was getting it on both the browsers. Also have stated in question about `margin-left` to the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this 
add this style to your anchor tag

```
<div class="col-md-9 text-center">
  <a href="#" style="float:left;display:block;margin-top: 3px;
      margin-left: 448px;">
   <img class="img-responsive" style="position: relative;
      width: 175px; display: inline;" src="/assets/header_other/reco.png">
  </a>    
</div>
```

now only the image will have the anchor properties not whole col-md-9 div

that's all folks

Comment: well he is not talking about how to send image in left but why its getting a tag if using margin-left? so please read question before answering. Thanx

Comment: so remove the margin styles from the img and put it to anchor tag.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do.

Comment: if you want to target your anchor to image only, it is better if you add styles to anchor tag other than img tag